# Resolved - Mass Action - Mass Database Update in Magento Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, module, grid, custom, massaction

I have this grid developed for the custom module. I added the mass delete action which works fine. But the mass Approve/Disapprove actions work only for one value, when I select multiple values I get this error.
Please help to resolve this:

[image]

Here is the code for the approve function in controller file:

```
    public function massApproveAction() {
       $requestIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
       if(!is_array($requestIds)) {
       Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select reqeust(s)'));
       } else { 
       try {    

        foreach ($requestIds as $requestId) {
            $RequestData = Mage::getModel('cpstest_productcomment/cps')->load($requestId); 
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $data = array('comment_status'=>'Approved');
            $model = Mage::getModel('cpstest_productcomment/cps')->addData($data);      
            }
                $model->setId($id)->save();
                echo "Data updated successfully.";

        } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct but at the time of saving data you set all request params in setId method. Please find below line and correct it.

```
$model->setId($id)->save();
```

Replace with below code

```
$model->setId($requestId)->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. With this code I don't get the error any more, but it still saves only one value.

Comment: Your solution is correct, I made a mistake and put it outside the loop, that's why it was only saving 1 value. Then I put it in the foreach loop and it works great :) Thank you!